# Regular Expression in C

Tags: c, regex

I'm trying to match a string "123,1234" using regex.h. Following pattern does the job:

```
"^[0-9]\{1,\},[0-9]\{1,\}$"
```

If I'm giving it as a commandline argument it works fine. But when I use it inside C code it does not work. Probably because identifying backward slashes as escape characters.

Sample Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]){
    regex_t regex;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];
    char * string, * pattern;

    string = "123,1234";
    pattern = "^[0-9]\{1,\},[0-9]\{1,\}$";

    if(regcomp(&regex, pattern, 0))
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
            exit(107);
    }

    if(!(reti = regexec(&regex, string, 0, NULL, 0)))
    {
            printf("MATCH\n");
    }
    else if(reti == REG_NOMATCH)
    {
            printf("NO MATCH\n");
    }
    else
    {
            regerror(reti, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
            exit(107);
    }

    regfree(&regex);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Difficult to judge by just a single sample, but the pattern looks way too complex, no? `^\d+,\d+$`

Comment: @Regexident '+' neither works in grep nor using regex.h

Comment: @Regexident I found it from here [link](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html) And it works in grep and as well as if we pass it to the program as a commandline argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is an ERE not a BRE, so you need to pass the `REG_EXTENDED` flag to `regcomp`. Then, as others have said, remove the backslashes too.

Answer (score 3):

`^[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}$`
Take out the `\` backslashes.  They escape the character immediately following.

Answer (score 2):

To override the slash as an escape sequence, in C one uses a slash to escape a slash, so `\` becomes `\\`.

However, since you are not passing the string to the command line, the curly braces `{` and `}` are not going to be caught by the shell's parser, so you could just try it without all of the slashes.

```
"^[0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,}$"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the slashes are being treated as escape characters, have you tried doubling up the slashes so that they are treated as escaped slashes?

ie

```
"^[0-9]\\{1,\\},[0-9]\\{1,\\}$"
```

Comment: @Dulanja: This one actually worked for me a minute ago. This, as well as **without** any backslashes, but **with** `REG_EXTENDED` set as flag in `regcomp()`, as seen in R..'s answer.

Comment: yes I missed 'REG_EXTENDED'. Now it works. I should have posted the sample code earlier. Thanks :)